# can I scroll a web page using selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('http://www.example.com')

search_items = []

for i in range(0, 20):   
    items = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="asrt%s"]/section[2]'
        % str(i))
    driver.items("window.scrollTo(0, Y)")

    print items.text
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to scroll to a WebElement you can use:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

Where element is the variable to a WebElement you have set.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, Y)")

Comment: my basic need is to move the scroll down 1 by 1 item i captured, because the web site will not display all item at a time. and i need to capture all item from that web site.